# How to resolve RootTagMissingFromViewException error while adding new Livewire component in Laravel 8 with Jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to add a new Livewire component to Laravel 8 Jetstream but looks I'm doing something wrong and getting the following error.

**Error:**

[image: RootTagMissingFromViewException]

```
Livewire\Exceptions\RootTagMissingFromViewException
Livewire encountered a missing root tag when trying to render a component. When rendering a Blade view, make sure it contains a root HTML tag
```

**Route:**

```php
// web.php
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/newEmployee', NewEmployee::class);
});
```

**Controller:**

```php
// app/Http/Livewire/NewEmployee.php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class NewEmployee extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.new-employee')->layout('layouts.app')->name('NewEmployee');
    }
}
```

**View:**

```html
<!-- resources/views/livewire/new-employee.blade.php  -->
<div>
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <h1> New Wmployee </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't (name) the method. Please define:

```php
return view('livewire.new-employee')->layout('layouts.app');
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: For me, this worked: *return view('livewire.new-employee')->extends('layouts.app');*

Answer (score 1):

You need add any HTML Tags in your livewire BLADE file. LiveWire need HTML TAG in BLADE file. So add simple TEST PAGE in LIVEWIRE BLADE. Issue should resolved.